# ASP.NET MVC Authentication and Session time Out

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can Some one suggest the best way to do the forms authentication in my asp.net mvc application. My requirement is, if user is idle for 5 mins application should automatically redirect to login page. What is the best approach?

Comment: You could enable slidingExpiration on your forms authentication cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Update your web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="AppName.Auth" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" timeout="300" path="/"  slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>

</system.web>
```

timeout="300" -> 5 minutes x 60 seconds

All the MVC actions decorated with [Authorize] attribute will redirect the user to login page after 5 mins of inactivity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have given the same way, but it is redirecting when I refresh my page. Not going automatically

Comment: ah looks like you are sending an async http request here. Correct, it wont redirect you. You have to do this manually. Hook up your own custom Authorize attribute  call it [AuthorizeUser] for example and write code that handle async request onAthorization event. search for how to do that online, it can be easily done.

Comment: Another way is to call a web api method instead of mvc method. The [Authorize] attribute of web api with System.Web.Http namespace does that for you. It will raise a 401 unauthorized response header which you can catch on client callback and act accordingly.